# How to add messages to a class with addClassRules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate a page with a large number of repeated rows of data.  Due to limited space, each row has it's own validation summary.

I use addClassRules to apply the validation rules to the page but the default error messages are too generic in the summary (e.g. "Field is required, Field is required etc).

Example:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
amount: {
    required: true,
    range: [0, 2000000]
},
comment: {
    maxlength: 51
},
owner: {
    notFirstOption: true
},
A: {
    required: function (element) {  
        return getParentElement($(element), "tr").find(".colB input.B").val().length > 0;
    },
    digits: true
}});
```

Can you apply custom messages for the rules in each validation class?  Ideally I'm after something like:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassMessages({
    amount: {
        required: "Amount is required",
        range: "Amount must be between 0 and 2,000,000"
    },
    comment: {
        maxlength: "Comment may be a maximum of 51 characters"
    },
    owner: {
        notFirstOption: "Please select an owner"
    },
    A: {
        required: "A is required if B is entered",
        digits: "A must be numeric"
    }});
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Thank you, you were bullseye

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the documentation, the answer is to alias the method that you want to call and add the custom message.

[Check the reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference) under the "Refactoring rules" heading:

```
// alias required to cRequired with new message
$.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,
"Customer name required");
// alias minlength, too
$.validator.addMethod("cMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength, 
// leverage parameter replacement for minlength, {0} gets replaced with 2
$.format("Customer name must have at least {0} characters"));
// combine them both, including the parameter for minlength
$.validator.addClassRules("customer", { cRequired: true, cMinlength: 2 });
```

Comment: You may need to use $.validator.format() in place of $.format

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using below code,

```
  $.validator.messages.accept = 'File must be JPG, GIF or PNG';

    $.validator.addClassRules("files", {            
      accept : "png|jpe?g|gif",  
      filesize : 2000000
    });
```

Comment: I recommend this solution because it is simple and straight forward as well as it works with inbuilt rules as well as custom rules. Of course, now there is also much more progress towards making it easy to add error messages in the plugin (just check the docs). Ohh, and btw you can also probably use `$.extend()` to combine your custom rule messages with inbuilt messages in a single step like `$.validator.messages = $.extend($.validator.messages, Object MyCustomMessages)` or like so.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a pretty heinous solution but hope for something a lot cleaner with a bit more time...

Anyway, by assigning the messages through jQuery metadata I'm able to customise them per class.

```
class="amount {validate:
                {messages:
                  {required:'Amount is required',
                   range: 'Amount must be between 0 and 2,000,000',
                   digits: 'Amount must be numeric'}
                }
              }"
```

...and so on for each of the fields in my grid rows.

I'll be looking at extending the 'addClassRules' method to accept a messages parameter but for now this works so it'll do.

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone's obviously interested in the response to this one here's the next step in my pursuit of an answer!

I've added methods into the plugin that allow the addition of class messages and amended the default message handler to pick these out.

Added before 'customMetaMessage'

```
customClassMessage: function (element, method) {
    //Get the elements class(es)
    var classes = $(element).attr("class").split(" ");

    //return any message associated with said class and method
    var m = $.validator.messages[classes[0]];

    return m && (m.constructor == String
        ? m
        : m[method]);
},
```

Amended 'defaultMessage' to include a call to the above method

```
defaultMessage: function (element, method) {
                return this.findDefined(
                this.customMessage(element.name, method),
                this.customMetaMessage(element, method),
                this.customClassMessage(element, method),
                // title is never undefined, so handle empty string as undefined
                !this.settings.ignoreTitle && element.title || undefined,
                $.validator.messages[method],
                "<strong>Warning: No message defined for " + element.name + "</strong>"
            );
            },
```

Added an 'addClassMessages' method

```
        addClassMessages: function (className, messages) {
        if (className.constructor == String) {
            $.validator.messages[className] = messages != undefined ? messages : $.validator.messages[className];
        }
        else {
            $.extend(this.messages, className);
        }
    },
```

I haven't been able to work out how to attach these additional methods outside of the plugin as yet.  At least I don't have to declare error messages in the 'class' attribute though.

```
jQuery.validator.addClassMessages({
    amount: {
        required: "Amount is required",
        range: "Amount must be between 0 and 2,000,000",
        digits: "Amount must be numeric"
    }
});
```

Comment: As per v1.15, the function `customMetaMessage` is now renamed `customDataMessage`.  And I modified the middle part of `customClassMessage` so the form-validation class doesn't have to be the first in the classes:
`var m = classes.map( function( c ) {  return $.validator.messages[c] }).filter( function( e ) {  return typeof e != "undefined" }); m = m[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Use **data-msg-required="Error message here"** with the element you like to do validation

```
<select name="account1" data-msg-required="Please select an account">
<option value="">--Select Account--</option>
<optgroup label="100-Assets">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answers requires to write custom method or common error messages, which sometimes not easily customised. Below one works for me which was mentioned in [github issue tracker](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1442):

```
$.validator.addClassRules = function (className, rules) {

    if (className.constructor === String) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[className] = rules;
        className = obj;
    }

    $.each(className, function (n, r) {
        $("." + n).each(function (i, e) {
            var self = $(e)
            self.rules('add', r);
        });
    });

}
```

**Usage:**

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    'firstname': {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "First name is required"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    amount: {
        required: true,
        range: [0, 2000000],
        messages: {required: "Required field!", range: "Invalid range!"}
    },
    comment: {
        maxlength: 51,
        messages: {maxlength: "Max 51 characters!"}
    }
})
```

I think that is what you are looking for, correct?

Comment: You'll have to hang on for me to check this but I'll get back to you when I've had a chance.  It's so simple it's bound to be right though!  Cheers

Comment: "messages" can be supplied to [.validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) but not to [addClassRules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/). I also tried @Martin Karlsson's suggestion with jquery-validation v1.19.3 and it had no impact on the message shown.