# jquery validate: Overriding default message via Alias for require_from_group fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a particular rule that is defined by class name rather than fieldname:

```
$.validator.addClassRules("fillone", {
        require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]
    });
```

I would like to override the default error message for that, so I tried this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("xrequire_from_group", $.validator.methods.required, 'Hey nutter, pick at least one');

$.validator.addClassRules("fillone", {
  xrequire_from_group: [1, ".fillone"]
});
```

I have here a fiddle to proof it works first without meddling with alias:

http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/fg6ae/1/

and here is what I get after alias:

http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/m9uNK/1/

As you can see, it breaks it. Both messages shall disappear after entering only one field. But it doesn't. Is this a bug?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247305/how-to-add-messages-to-a-class-with-addclassrules

Comment: I have tried the alias solution. It works for simple stuff like `required` (as shown in the link), but it doesn't work for `require_from_group`. I just tried it. :(

Comment: Please construct a jsFiddle to demonstrate your issue.  Here's a starting point already with the proper includes:  http://jsfiddle.net/fg6ae/

Comment: @Sparky: Many thanks for the layout. I have two fiddles to show you before and after. Please see updated question. I think it is a bug or I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: Please clean-up and clarify the question.  Firstly, you state that you can't get a custom message, then in your edit, you're actually using a custom message, but state that it doesn't clear out properly.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, my intention is to keep the functionality as it is and simply override the default message. I have now completely revised the question to point this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, I'll suggest that you use [the `groups` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to simply display one message for both fields.  Logically, since you don't require both fields to be filled out, there shouldn't be an error message next to both fields.  It seems like a single message telling the user to pick one of two makes more sense.

You then need to use `errorPlacement:` option to place it wherever you want.

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/m9uNK/2/

```
var validator = $(form).validate({
    groups: {
        groupname: "field1 field2"  // as per docs, "groupname" is arbitrary
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "field1" || element.attr("name") == "field2") {
            error.insertAfter("[name='field2']");  // adjust this accordingly
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);  // this is default placement for everything else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated. But this is not the solution I was hoping for. I like how it is already implemented. Having two error messages is exactly what I need, since the two fields are not next to each other in my form and it makes it easier to spot which two are meant to be filled. All I need to do is to change the custom message, this solution here is an alternative solution that doesn't match my case. :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a working solution, there was a subtle mistake in the code.

```
$.validator.addMethod("xrequire_from_group", $.validator.methods.required, 'Hey nutter, pick at least one');
```

replace with

```
$.validator.addMethod("xrequire_from_group", $.validator.methods.require_from_group, 'Hey nutter, pick at least one');
```

Now it works, finally!!!