# jQuery.validator.addClassRules() doesn't show error message. Why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a little problem.
I'm using MVC 4 and "jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1".

I inserting in script section custom validation, something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nameExist", function (value, element, param) {
            var notError = true;
            if (value == 'Hello')
            {
                 notError = false;
            }
            return notError;
        }, 'The name exists');
```

And create class with new validation

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("nameExistErrClass", { nameExist: true });
```

Then in html section do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Home.CopyData(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "copyForm" }))
{

...

@Html.TextBox("newName", string.Empty, new { type = "text", @class = "nameExistErrClass"})
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="newName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

...

}
```

After submitting this form with text "Hello" looks like validation is working, but Error Message is

> Warning: No message defined for newName

**How to display a message 'The name exists'?**

P.s.
If I adding attribute

> required = "required"

to element 'newName', everything is fine and message is taken from default messages.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247305/how-to-add-messages-to-a-class-with-addclassrules

Comment: Seems to me you're doing this correctly, working example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/xC6nb/

Comment: Please show the _rendered_ HTML of your form.

Answer (score -1):

Now I got it! Sorry for all the confusion. The JavaScript part is working well. The problem is that such an overload `Html.BeginForm(String, FormMethod, Object)` doesn't exist. Please tell me what you try to do so that I can give you the right advice. I don't even understand the `MVC.Home.CopyData()` part. Could you please tell me more about that too. I think you migth choose the wrong approach for it.

I hope this is going to help you!

Comment: **Quote**: _"You have to pass an object to the `addClassRules` method instead of two arguments."_ ~ No, you are incorrect.  [You **can** also pass two arguments as `(string, object)`, using `jQuery.validator.addClassRules(name, rules)` as per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/). Also see Ryley's working jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/xC6nb/

Comment: Ryley's demo works fine when you realize the field is not "required" and any value _except_ "Hello" passes validation.  Your version of the `addClassRules` method works just the same as Ryley's:  http://jsfiddle.net/xC6nb/2/

Comment: Also, take notice how the logic of your `nameExist` method is completely backwards.  http://jsfiddle.net/xC6nb/1/

Comment: It's too late I should go to bed. I completely got mixed up. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Sparky, could you please remove your *not useful* vote because I changed the whole answer. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, this "answer" is now just a comment.

Comment: Right, but I cannot delete it and I need 50 points to do a comment. I think this is the best I can do right now.