# jQuery.validator.addClassRules not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i consult this posts
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624622/728750
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402711/728750

### this way i tried but no luck

```
<form action="#">
<input type="text" id="name1" class="fileName" name="name1" />
<input type="text" id="name2" class="fileName" name="name2"/>
<input type="text" id="name3" class="fileName" name="name3"/>
<input type="text" id="name4" class="fileName" name="name4"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addClassRules({
        fileName:{
        required: true
    }
    });

$.validator.messages.fileName = 'File name mandatory!';

    $("form").validate();
});
```

my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/Nbcj9/395/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **required** to **cRequired** and then override the **cRequired** message by adding $.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"File name mandatory!");

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addClassRules({
        fileName:{
                  cRequired: true
                 }       
    });

   $.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"File name mandatory!");

   $("form").validate();
});
```

Updated fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/Nbcj9/397/

Comment: why we need to change the name required from crequire? please discuss the idea

Comment: "required" is a default validation rule and it has a default message - "This field is required". So the above code overrides the "required" rule by giving an alias "cRequired"

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316776/can-we-use-wildcard-with-jquery-validator

Answer (score 1):

Because the required rule has a default message you may change it:

```js
$.extend($.validator.messages, {required: "File name mandatory!"});
$.validator.addClassRules("fileName", {required: true});

$(function () {
  $("form").validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="name1" class="fileName" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" id="name2" class="fileName" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" id="name3" class="fileName" name="name3"/>
    <input type="text" id="name4" class="fileName" name="name4"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: what $.extend does? give me any link from where i can know about the usage of $.extend ?

Comment: which jquery file has $.extend function ?

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316776/can-we-use-wildcard-with-jquery-validator

Comment: I'm tired and I have to finish to prepare my mathematics class for tomorrow.it's important for my students. I hope you may forgive me. Bye

Comment: no problem give answer tomorrow when u get some time.