# jquery validate addClassRules

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate input fields by class name, for this using the function: addClassRules. This validation is working when i click the input field but its not taking in the form validation when submitting.

```
$(".savedns-button").on("click", function(e) {

$.validator.addClassRules({
    content_A: {
        required: true,
        IP4Checker: true
    },
    content_AAAA: {
        required: true,
        IP6Checker: true
    } 
});

$("#saverecords").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorElement : 'div',
    errorLabelContainer: '.dns-add-error',


});
$("#saverecords").valid();
});
```

HTML inputs

```
<input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left input-sm content_MX" value="10 mail.server.tld">
<input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left input-sm content_A" value="8.8.8.8">
```

This new version is validating when selecting the input field but not when submitting the form.

The problem is, that i got different kind of input data on the same name input field.
So we got A AAAA MX records etc, i identify them by different class name: content_RECORDTYPE. This is where i try to use different validations for different inputs in the same fields.

Full form

```html
<form method="POST" action="/domeinnaam/dns/save" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="saverecords" class="col-12" style="margin-bottom: 40px;" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="t5JbyIe9wcCJIojknpfGtUyGJKRik89AHF4JZ7mv">

    <input type="hidden" class="domain_id" name="domain_id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="domain" name="domain" value="jantjekomtthuis.nl">

    <div class="form-panel">

                <div class="row form-group" id="17238" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17238">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm valid" value="@" required="" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm valid" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV" selected="">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_SRV valid" value="100 1 443 sip1.domnain.tkld" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17238')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17236" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17236">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX" selected="">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_MX" value="20 mail.domain.tld" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17236')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17234" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17234">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX" selected="">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_MX" value="20 mail.domain.tld" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17234')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17229" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17229">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT" selected="">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_TXT" value="&quot;v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 ~all&quot;" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17229')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17226" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17226">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT" selected="">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_TXT" value="&quot;v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all&quot;" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17226')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17202" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17202">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX" selected="">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_MX" value="20 mail.domain.tld" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17202')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17200" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17200">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX" selected="">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_MX" value="10 mail.domain.tld" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17200')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17123" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17123">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A" selected="">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_A error" value="8.8.8" required="" aria-describedby="content-error" aria-invalid="true">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17123')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row form-group" id="17121" data-removedomain="jantjekomtthuis.nl">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="record_id" name="record_id[]" value="17121">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Naam</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" value="@" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>TTL</b></label>
                <select name="expire[]" id="expire" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
                    <option value="60">1 min.</option>
                    <option value="300">5 min.</option>
                    <option value="3600" selected="">1 uur</option>
                    <option value="86400">1 dag</option>
                    <option value="604800">7 dagen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Type</b></label>
                <select name="type[]" id="type" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="">
                    <option value="A" selected="">A</option>
                    <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                    <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                    <option value="MX">MX</option>
                    <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                    <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-right: 55px;">
                <label class="d-block d-lg-none"><b>Content</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="content[]" id="content" style="font-size: 14px;" class="form-control pull-left required input-sm content_A error" value="8" required="" aria-describedby="content-error" aria-invalid="true">
                <button class="btn btn-delete pull-right btn-sm delete-record" style="position: absolute; right: 15px;" type="button" onclick="delete_record('17121')">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M448 294.2v-76.4c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24H286.2V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-76.4c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v137.8H24c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v76.4c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h137.8V456c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h76.4c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V318.2H424c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col" style="margin-bottom: 40px; right: -15px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-groen pull-right savedns-button" style="margin-left: 10px;">Opslaan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right disabled">Reset</button>
        </div>

    <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</form>
```

Greatings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.validator.addClassRules not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311488/jquery-validator-addclassrules-not-working)

Comment: Updated the code some more.