# How to display custom messages with jQuery rules validation using addClassRules

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I display custom messages with jQuery when I'm using addClassRules? This is my code :-

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    land_workshop_covered_area :
    {
        required : true,
        number: true,
        min : 0.01,
        dollarsscents : true
    },
    land_workshop_trade :
    {
        required : true
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add messages to a class with addClassRules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247305/how-to-add-messages-to-a-class-with-addclassrules)

Comment: Yup, It's working but I have to add method for each field. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found It. We need to create method for field :-

// set custom message for workshop covered area

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wcaRequired", jQuery.validator.methods.required,"Please enter workshop covered area");
```

// set custom message for workshop trade

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wcatRequired", jQuery.validator.methods.required,"Please select any trade");
```

After that call above methods Instead of required :-

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
        land_workshop_covered_area :
        {
            wcaRequired : true,
            number: true,
            min : 0.01,
            dollarsscents : true
        },
        land_workshop_trade :
        {
            wcatRequired : true
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm having to do the same thing and wondered if you have to write separate messages for each attribute like number, min etc. will you end up writing a new method for each or can this be extended?

Answer (score 1):

Below one works for me which was mentioned in [github issue tracker](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1442):

```
$.validator.addClassRules = function (className, rules) {

    if (className.constructor === String) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[className] = rules;
        className = obj;
    }

    $.each(className, function (n, r) {
        $("." + n).each(function (i, e) {
            var self = $(e)
            self.rules('add', r);
        });
    });

}
```

**Usage:**

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    'firstname': {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "First name is required"
        }
    }
});
```